# Regex to split on whitespace but not escaped whitespace

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to split on standard whitespace `" "` but not escaped whitespace "\ "

For example, with the string `'my name\ is\ max'` (single quotes so `\` is literal)

I want to get `["my", "name\ is\ max"]`

I've tried this regex: `/[^\\]\s/`

but the result is this:

```
=> ["m", "name\\ is\\ max"]
```

This is close but I don't know how to keep the `y` in `my`

---

*edit*

As another example consider this string:

```
"./db/users/WGDl-HATof-uhdtT7sPfog: email=maxpleaner@gmail.com name=max\\ p"
```

I want to split it into three:

```
[
  "./db/users/WGDl-HATof-uhdtT7sPfog:",
  "email=maxpleaner@gmail.com",
  "name=max\\ p"
]
```

Comment: That means a literal backslash is also doubled, right? `'my name\\ is\ max'` would be `[ "my", "name\\\\", "is\\ max"]`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm trying to split on whitespace that is not preceeded by a backslash. So I don't think that's correct.

Comment: Then `.split(/(?<!\\)\s/)`. Or `.scan(/(?:[^\s\\]|\\.)+/)`

Comment: Try `shellwords` lib, no need for a regexp. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding

> I'm trying to split on whitespace that is not preceeded by a backslash.

If you only care about backslash before whitespace and there are no other special cases to consider, use a negative lookbehind `(?<!\\)` before `\s`:

```
s.split(/(?<!\\)\s/)
```

Here, `\s+` matches 1+ whitespaces if not preceded with a backslash (`(?<!\\)` is a *negative lookbehind* that checks if the text to the left of the current location matches the pattern, and if yes, the match is failed).

In case there are multiple whitespaces to consider, and in case there is need to deal with escape sequences, use

```
s.scan(/(?:[^\s\\]|\\.)+/)
```

See the [Ruby demo](http://ideone.com/shV86c)

Here, `(?:[^\s\\]|\\.)+` matches 1 or more chars other than a backslash and whitespace (`[^\s\\]`) or any escape sequence (`\\.`). Add `/m` modifier to make `.` match line break chars, too.

Comment: Can you see my edit to the question please? There's a second test case that this wasn't working with.

Comment: See http://ideone.com/Ji3HsM. Actually, the splitting I suggested also results in expected result: http://ideone.com/4sY1E2

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
require 'shellwords'

'my name\ is\ max'.shellsplit
# => ["my", "name is max"]
```

No need for a regexp.

Comment: Never heard of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this:
`"./db/users/WGDl-HATof-uhdtT7sPfog: email=maxpleaner@gmail.com name=max\\ p".split(/(?<![\\])[\s](?![\\])/)`.

A break-down of the regex `(?<![\\])[\s](?![\\])` :

`(?<![\\])` This tells the regex engine to match a whitespace not preceded by a backslash "\" (escaped here with another backslash)

`[\s]` This is a character class for a 'space'

`(?![\\])` This tells the regex engine to match a whitespace that is preceded by a backslash "\" (escaped here with another backslash)

Comment: Why do you use a negative lookahead? Shouldn't the negative lookbehind be enough?

Comment: Good question. I was thinking, for whatever reason, that there might be instances where there would be a whitespace followed by a backslash, but I now that I think about it I guess it's not necessary.